# Realm (Android/Kotlin) - How to perform a query which allows you to test if all objects match as a part of values in an array of values

Tags: android, realm, realm-list

Context :

1. Some content (Sheet, Category, etc.) are protected by groups. (Content class has 2 RealmLists of groups, the first "groupsOneOf" an the second "groupsAllOf")
2. Users can be in groups (User has one RealmList "groups")
3. Some content is available only for user which is *at least in one of the content's group*.
4. Some content is available only for user which is *in all of content's group*.

For *"at least in one of the content's group"*, I found 'in' operator in documentation :

> This allows you to test if objects match any value in an array of values.

But for the second, no way to perform this kind of query. I searched solution in other posts but some people seems to say that's not supported right now. In iOS, it seems to be available with NSPredicate but not in java.

Here is my code :

```
fun <E: RealmObject> RealmQuery<E>.groupsAllowed(): RealmQuery<E>{
    val userGroupsIds = realm.queryUserConnected()?.findFirst()?.groups?.toGroupIds()
    if(userGroupsIds == null || userGroupsIds.isEmpty()){
        isEmpty("groupsAllOf")
        isEmpty("groupsOneOf")
    }else{
        beginGroup()
            beginGroup()
                isEmpty("groupsOneOf")
                or()
                `in`("groupsOneOf.id", userGroupsIds.toTypedArray())
            endGroup()
            //beginGroup()
                //isEmpty("groupsAllOf")
                //or()
                //TODO
            //endGroup()
        endGroup()
    }
    return this
}
```

Currently I'm performing a post filter when I get the RealmResults for groupsAllOf :

```
fun <E: RealmObject> E.groupsAllowed(userGroupIds: List<String>): E?{
    val groupsAllOf: RealmList<Group>? = when(this){
        is Sheet -> groupsAllOf
        is Category -> groupsAllOf
        else -> null
    }
    if(groupsAllOf == null || groupsAllOf.isEmpty()){
        return this
    }else{
        return if(userGroupIds.containsAll(groupsAllOf.toGroupIds())) this else null
    }
}

fun <E: RealmObject> RealmResults<E>.groupsAllowed(): List<E>{
    val userGroupIds = realm.queryUserConnected().findFirst()?.groups?.toGroupIds()?: emptyList()
    val listAllowed = arrayListOf<E>()
    this.forEach { it.groupsAllowed(userGroupIds)?.let { contentAllowed ->  listAllowed.add(contentAllowed) } }
    return listAllowed
}

fun RealmList<Group>.toGroupIds(): List<String> = arrayListOf<String>().apply { this@toGroupIds.forEach { group -> this.add(group.id) } }
```

But this is annoying because I have to no forget to call this function when I get the RealmResults :/

Some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you titled it realm java but its kotlin :/

Comment: Yeah to avoid iOS developer to come accidentally here, by java I mean the Android world, I will change the title :p. By the way this is the query the problem.

Comment: It sure would be nice to access the `ALL` predicate, wouldn't it? Nag Realm at https://github.com/realm/realm-java/pull/6116 because there is no other way.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce the rawPredicate isn't available right now isn't it ?

Comment: nope. hence why i said they need to be nagged to add it faster :D

Comment: Ah OK I misunderstood the word "nag", my bad. OK I will x). I used Greendao on a large project and now I need to migrate it on realm to support string primary key, kotlin and avoid headaches with more than 40 tables. These features are for me totally obvious, I hope it will come very soon :)